# Use matrix notation to denote the residual sum-of-squares (RSS)

Tags: statistics

The usual way to denote RSS is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\hat{Y_i})^2$

By writing in the matrix form $Y=X \beta + \epsilon$. Then I know $\hat Y=PY$

Thus, the RSS=$||    (I_n-P)Y    ||^2 = ||    (I_n-P)(Y-X\beta)    ||^2= \epsilon^T (I_n-P)\epsilon$

How to see the above last two equal signs?